# How to combine Google Apps Script with JavaScript?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use HTML to create form, use JavaScript to interact with users, and use Google Apps Script to create workflow. But I don't know who to combine Google Apps Script with JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you Google it...??

Comment: The following [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles), check: _Workflow and End-to-End Examples_.

Check out the documentation, specifically [Html Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a Google Apps Script project (from drive, create script).

using the [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service) class you can create the HTML page with the form and the client Javascript (included Jquery if you need it) and of course can use Google Apps Script (server javascript).

You need to make a web apps, adding a doGet function in the Google Apps Script code (.gs). Example:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}
```

You have to save a version of the app and then publishing as web apps (using the menu).

Then you have to add an index.html file with the form: menu file, new, "html file" and then include a javascript file. Example:

```
<div>
  <form action="">
     <input type="text" value="" name="name">
      ......

   var msg= "You can also include server side javascript like this";

   <? = serverSideVariableOrFunction ?>

  </form>
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  client javascript code here

</script>
```

If you like you can put the javascript in a separate html page of the project. Add  a function for including other files inside html. Example

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

And then insert in the html page:

```
<?!= include(file.js) ?>
```

You could also using a js file, saving it in a public drive folder, that can be linked inside the html page using the link:

```
https://googledrive.com/host/idOfTheFolder/javascrispFile.js
```

For getting the Post request you can use the doPost(e) method, for example:

```
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log('value of the name parameter is: ' + e.parameter.name);
}
```

You can learn Google apps script going to the [Google developer web site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).

---

Comment: Is there a way to pass the value from javascript file to Google Apps Script? e.g.: I have created a table with html, and set the table width = "100%", I could use "document.getElementById("mytable").offsetWidth" get the table's width, but how could I pass this value to Google Apps Script?